# rendered animations are jumpy

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation

The thing that doesn't make sense the most is that the samples on the images are only 50, then the rendered animation is only 100 samples, but it jumps all weird. Usually I render it as a Avi JPG, (but I have tried multiple others). So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please try to better describe what "jumpy" means, maybe an embedded gif or a linked video... also does it happen with other (simpler) files too?

Comment: thanks. it is quite hard to describe without just showing you. I don't actually know how to make a gif, but here is a dropbox link to where you can watch it (this part is about 6 seconds for simplicity)

Comment: ..here... where? edit your question and paste the link there... (another option could be share it through yt or vimeo, etc)